# FFMPEG Convert image format with best possible output?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, compression, conversion, codec

With the standard command you can theoretically convert almost anything (`ffmpeg -i input.png output.tiff`),
but I'm afraid that the output will differ from the input in terms of quality and/or colorspace.

If I add `-codec copy`, so far everything stays the same, but also the file type and only the extension in the name changes.
I'm not so sure that's the right way to go either.

As far as I know you can adjust the quality of JPG with `-qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1`.

Is there anything in particular to look out for when compressing (`-compression_algo packbits`)? You could go with raw, but packbits has at least some compression and is also lossless.

Is it better to leave out the pixel format (`-pix_fmt rgba`) so that it might stay the same (if it does), or is there a specific format you should use?

And does the DPI need to be set or does it stay the same (`-dpi <int>`)? And does that change the quality?

And then there is the Prediction Method (`-pred <int>`), which you can set for PNG files, which is also some sort of compression, if I understand it correctly.

I don't think there is a specific command with all the important arguments to get the output with whatever format in the best possible quality, but what do I have to look for in which format?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Any image you have is already in the best quality available to you - this applies even if is has been squeezed to death in a jpg. You can't get back what has been thrown away. btw, DPI has no relevance at all to a digital image until the moment it is printed on paper. Until that point all it has is dimensions in pixels.

Comment: @Tetsujin when I want to convert a jpg or any other image format for example to a png, I would like the output to be as faithful to the original as possible. I know that it may not work in quality (e.g. if I convert to JPG), but at least the image should not differ in color (by color space or similar)

Comment: Aside from the fact that all you will gain in doing that is a larger file [therefore a truly pointless exercise], colour management/profiling should not be changed during a simple conversion unless you are fully aware of what each profile is for & why.